# iPhone simulator watch app icon missing?

Tags: ios, iphone, icons, watchkit, xcode7

Anyone has any idea why I have a missing icon here?
I use Xcode 7.0.1.

Could you tell me what am I missing now?

[image]

Comment: Reset simulator and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if all images in the xcasset of your App and Watch app are present and are in the correct size.

Comment: Would you tell me which icon set the icon is referencing for?

Comment: I had the same problem yesterday... In the WatchApp you should define the image for "Apple Watch Companion Settings". Both image with the correct size

Comment: Add also the "iPhone App iOS7-9" in the xcassets of your iOS App

Comment: But attention! Also in my case, in the simulator your don't see the image nut in the real device yes!

Comment: Ahh then I think this is some kind of bug. I will try with the real device thanks.